# how to get arm specific cpu info on arm-based ubuntu

Tags: hardware, arm, cpuinfo, lshw, inxi

Is there ARM specific hardware information utilities for CPU, Graphic card, etc.?

lshw, inxi, /proc/cpuinfo are well known utilities or method but it does not provide ARM specific informations such as model, model name, L1/L2 cache.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Did you tried `dmidecode`?

Comment: I tested on firefly RK3399 board. 
```sh
$ sudo dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.0
# No SMBIOS nor DMI entry point found, sorry.
```
dmidecode depends on SMBIOS or DMI but firefly RK3399 does not have either one.